# azure ad b2c; get from JWT Token to AuthenticationToken

Tags: azure

I am following this tutorial on how to authorize my app to access my middleware:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication?pivots=vs2022-windows

At the end of the GetAuthenticationToken() function; this is returned:

```
var x = new AuthenticationToken
        {
            DisplayName = result?.Account?.Username ?? "",
            ExpiresOn = result?.ExpiresOn ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
            Token = result?.AccessToken ?? "",
            UserId = result?.Account?.Username ?? ""
        };
```

I am however not using Azure AD but Azure AD B2C so the tutorial only works half way.

I got to a point where I am able to retrieve a token:

```
 var result = await authService.AcquireTokenSilent(CancellationToken.None);
        var token = result?.IdToken;
        if (token != null)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var data = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            if (data != null)
            {
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Name: {data.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("name"))?.Value}");
                //await Toast.Make(stringBuilder.ToString()).Show();
            }
        }
```

This is what lies on data:

[image]

So I know that I am logged in and in return retrieve a token.
But if I know try to put stuff onto my AuthenticationToken; this is what I get:

[image]

So nothing is on there.

This is the whole function:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationToken> GetAuthenticationToken()
{
    var result = await authService.AcquireTokenSilent(CancellationToken.None);
    var token = result?.IdToken;
    if (token != null)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var data = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        if (data != null)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Name: {data.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("name"))?.Value}");
        }
    }

    var x = new AuthenticationToken
    {
        DisplayName = result?.Account?.Username ?? "",
        ExpiresOn = result?.ExpiresOn ?? DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
        Token = result?.AccessToken ?? "",
        UserId = result?.Account?.Username ?? ""
    };

    return x;
}
```

How do I get from the result to my token? And why doesnt it transfer?